# wp7 webbrowser cant see JS alert messages?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I access the same webpage on the server with iOS, android and wp7, the others are fine, but wp7 webbrowser cant see JS alert messages.
I set IsScriptEnabled=True, still dont work.
The only way to show alert messages in WebBrowser is to use ScriptNotify and change codes on the server side(add Window.external.notify) ??

Answer (score 1):

It seems that WebBrowser in Windows Phone doesn't support 'alert' statement.